# Get a list of the latest items grouped by a different property in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework Entity `Shoe` that has a one to many relationship with another Entity `Person`. Each `Person` has many `Shoe`s. I want to get a list of the latest shoes each person has.

```
public class Shoe {

  public Long PersonId { get; set; }
  public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }

}
```

I tried this:

```
var latestShoesPerPerson = _dbContext.Shoe
    .GroupBy(shoe => shoe.PersonId)
    .Select(shoes => shoes.OrderByDescending(shoe => shoe.PurchaseDate).First());
```

But, I got this error
`orderbydescending could not be translated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a GroupBy is an implicit Key+Collection. It actually has a number of "flavours" to do subtly different things. The one you would be looking for to get the results like that would be `GroupBy<TSource,TKey,TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TKey>, Func<TKey,IEnumerable<TSource>,TResult>)`

Using this, the expression would look more like this:

```
var latestShoesPerPerson = _dbContext.Shoe
    .GroupBy(shoe => shoe.PersonId, (personId, shoes) => shoes.OrderByDescending(s => s.PurchaseDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList(); // list of the earliest shoe for each person.
```